# Passing color hex code but style doesn't changed in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using 'prop-types' to pass color hex code string to a component while printing the log, the passed props giving me the correct result but when I am applying the hex code string to style its does not reflect on UI

> Index.js

```
import Logo from './Logo';
import styles from './styles';

export { Logo, styles,};
```

> Logo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';
const logoBg = require('../../images/background.png');
const logo = require('../../images/logo.png');

const Logo = ({logoBgTintColor, logoTintColor}) => {
const logoBackgroundColor = [styles.logoBackground];
const logoColor = [styles.logo];

if (logoBgTintColor) {
  console.log(logoBgTintColor)
  console.log(logoBackgroundColor)
  logoBackgroundColor.push({ tintColor: logoBgTintColor});
}

if (logoTintColor) {
  logoColor.push({ tintColor: logoTintColor });
}

  return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      style={styles.logoBackground}
      source={logoBg}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={logo} />
    </Image>
  </View>
  );

};

Logo.propTypes = {
  logoBgTintColor: PropTypes.string,
  logoTintColor: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Logo;
```

> styles.js

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

const imageWidth =  Dimensions.get('window').width / 2;

 export default EStyleSheet.create({
     $largeContainerSize: imageWidth - 60,
     $largeImageSize: imageWidth/3,

     container: {
       // backgroundColor: 'red',
         alignItems: 'center',
     },
     logoBackground: {
        tintColor: '$primaryBlue',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '$largeContainerSize',
        height: '$largeContainerSize',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
     },
     logo: {
        // tintColor: '$primaryWhite',
         resizeMode: 'contain',
     },

 });
```

These are the dependencies I am using.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "color": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

Comment: Does other styling work?

Comment: @bennygenel yes others are working fines, actually, I am trying to make a useable component so that I can change the color whenever i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override/extend the styling of the component with giving an array of objects.

**Example**

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      style={[styles.logoBackground, { tintColor: this.state.tintColor }]}
      source={logoBg}>
      <Image style={[styles.logo, { tintColor: this.props.tintColor }]} source={logo} />
    </Image>
  </View>
  );
```

Comment: Its work. Awesome but in my code what is the issue due to which it's not working

Comment: @AbdulKarim I never used react-native-extended-stylesheet before so I can't be sure but It can be related to extended-stylesheet needs to be built when the app initiates and overriding after the build is a little bit complicated.